# Oversampling methods for numerical data (regression)

Tags: regression, machine-learning, unbalanced-classes, oversampling, smote

There are many oversampling methods for categorical labels (for example SMOTE and Rose, etc.).

But, are there oversampling method for numerical labels (the thing that I want to predict with my features), in the sense that it applies something similar SMOTE or Rose for the label that is highly skewed?
(I don't want to normalize or scale my label/class) for regression types of tasks?

Comment: Have you gone through the linear regression diagnostics in the normal way? http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/39-regression-model-diagnostics/161-linear-regression-assumptions-and-diagnostics-in-r-essentials/. You can transform the data if necessary e.g. log etc.

Comment: [It is not clear that oversampling even helps us in the classification setting.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/357466/are-unbalanced-datasets-problematic-and-how-does-oversampling-purport-to-he)